# Dual norm of the k-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that the dual norm of the k-norm on $R^n$ and $C^n$ is

$$\lVert x\rVert^D_{[k]}=\max\left\{\frac{1}{k} \| x\|_1,\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}\right\}.$$

The k-norm is defined as the sum of the k largest magnitudes of the enteries in x, i.e.

$\lVert x\rVert_{[k]}=\lvert x_{i1}\rvert+.....+\lvert x_{ik}\rvert$ where, $\lvert x_{i1}\rvert\geq\lvert x_{i2}\rvert\geq.....\geq\lvert x_{in}\rvert$

Your assistance is required

Comment: So in this sense is the "3" norm the sum of the 3 largest?

Comment: Yes it seems so

Comment: For my curiosity: where does it show up?

Comment: This is a problem from Matrix Analysis Book by Horn and Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you mean : $|x|^D_k = \max\{||x||_1/k, ||x||_\infty\}$ ?

This is simple if you write out the definition of dual norm:

$|x|^D_k = \sup_{||y||_k = 1} y'x$

where $||y||_k$ is the primal norm.

Now $x_i = ||x||_\infty$ is the component with the largest value of then the $\sup$ happens with $y_i=1$.